# While using scrapy its ignoring blank values while extracting values

Tags: python, null, web-scraping, scrapy, extract

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from sample3.items import taamaaItem

class taamaaSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "taamaa"
   allowed_domains = ["taamaa.com"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.taamaa.com/store-directory/"]

   def parse(self, response):
       sel = Selector(response)
       sites = sel.xpath('//div/div[@class="section clearfix col-md-12"]')
       items = []
       list1 = []
       list2 = []
       for site in sites:
           list1 = sites[0].xpath('//div[@class="pull-left col-md-3 merchant"]/div[@class="name"]/a/text()').extract()
           list2 = sites[0].xpath('//div[@class="pull-left col-md-3 merchant"]/div[@class="url"]/a/text()').extract()
       for index in range(len(list2)):
           td = taamaaItem()
           td['name'] = list1[index] 
           td['link'] = list2[index] 
           items.append(td)
       return items
```

While extracting data it leaves the blank value and fetches the next value of link, thus incorrecting my data alignment.

Example
if
**A = a , B = , C = c, D = d, E = e**

it fetches the output
**A = a , B = c , C = d , D = e , E = a**

and I want the output to be like this

**A = a , B = , C = c, D = d, E = e**

how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 strange things:

- you are using absolute XPath expressions in your loop
- and you applying them to `sites[0]` in your loop for each iteration

For your problem grouping 2 lists with some empty text elements, you can use the same structure with a loop on `sites` but extracting `name` and `link` in each iteration,
so you don't need intermediate lists

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from sample3.items import taamaaItem

class taamaaSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "taamaa"
   allowed_domains = ["taamaa.com"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.taamaa.com/store-directory/"]

   def parse(self, response):
       sel = Selector(response)
       sites = sel.xpath('//div/div[@class="section clearfix col-md-12"]')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           td = taamaaItem()           
           td['name'] = site.xpath("""
                .//div[@class="pull-left col-md-3 merchant"]
                    /div[@class="name"]/a/text()""").extract()
           td['link'] = site.xpath("""
                .//div[@class="pull-left col-md-3 merchant"]
                    /div[@class="url"]/a/text()""").extract()
           items.append(td)
       return items
```

See how I use relative XPath expression (`.//div......`)